# Using Bootstrap Grid for a Tile System but without JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a ruleset in Bootstrap that demands that we never exceed a 12 column layout. I read the docs on why this is, but in the way I'm using the grid for this little module, I'm not sure the ruleset applies. Here is my fiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lcx2k2t/

Here is a portion of the markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 component">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-plus</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-cloud</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-envelope</span>
     </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-pencil</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-glass</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a demo toolbar, and if you notice when you resize the output, the tiles adjust to the change of the viewport. However, if you notice my markup, I'm really using bootstrap grid classes incorrectly (I've leveraging the fact that if you exceed 12, anything after that point will wrap to the next line). I've cross browser tested this, but can anyone tell me why my approach may be volatile in the end? By the way, I wrapped a div with a grid class of col-xs-12 around the tiles so that I could get the padding that my tiles are not applying, since I am not using bootstrap like I should. I do know that this approach will skew centering and such, but in my case, not an issue.

Comment: In addition to what @THiCe said, if a responsive grid is what you are looking for, there are plenty of simple solutions: [this](https://github.com/vulpcod3z/vc-tools/blob/6905bf0fdbead03f51ffb9f128f027bf00cd2398/vc-grid.css) for instance, is a very simple css solution for grids.

Comment: That's a lot of markup for a simple thing. Even the example page http://getbootstrap.com/components/ doesn't use the columns, it creates a custom unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking...

Assuming you want to know if it's okay to exceed 12 in one row: I think that's okay. Twitter Bootstrap doesn't do anything (anymore) with `:first-child` or `:last-child` elements in a row, so don't worry to exceed 12.

I would though recommend to only use `col-*-1`, `col-*-2`, `col-*-3`, `col-*-4`, `col-*-6` or `col-*-12` classes because 12 is divisible by these numbers.

Comment: Yep, I'm just asking if it is okay to exceed 12 in one row, if it gives me the outcome I'd expect. Agreed on the col 1, col 2, col 3, etc configuration ruleset.

Comment: Ideally if you use the row class I guess you shouldn't exceed a value higher than 12 or it could cause some slight issues, what those issues are I can't say. However, your code shouldn't have any issues, it's simply doing what the Bootstrap grid system was designed to do: if the width of the columns at a particular viewport width exceeds 12 for a given row, it'll wrap the column that's causing it to go over.